# Creating a Looping Filter with Indirect function - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

(Ultimately trying to creating a labor log from multiple sheets)

For each "project" I create a new sheet from a template.  Each new sheet is automatically renamed to the project number and the number is added to a master list.

In each new project sheet there is a section for labor and material.

I am trying to have the filter function crawl each sheet listed in the master list and return all the labor information from multiple sheets.

*Master list copied to a helper row on test sheet (L3:L)*

*Labor notation (`INDIRECT SHEET!I21:I`)*

*Labor hours  `(INDIRECT SHEET!H21:H`)*

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way.

*Current code only returns the first sheet in the list: `=filter({indirect("'"&L3:L&"'!H21:H")},{indirect("'"&L3:L&"'!I21:I")} = "Labor")`*

Comment: Can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: this can be done only via script or else it needs to be pre-written (hardcoded)

Comment: I have tried to make a copy of the sheet and removed private information.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18n8PHfQSl5-e4zSmqCzgQLZoc4hVzWzSVUDHbgrQcxI/edit?usp=sharing  It lost some formatting so I hope its not too confusing.   Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You need to use a script to do this rather than through formulae alone.*

#### More Information:

Some things are too complex to be done in Sheets with formulae alone. In these cases, a written script can be used to accomplish where functionality is lacking.

You can open the script editor from the `Tools > Script editor` menu item in the Sheets UI.

#### Code:

```js
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function appendToLog() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var log = ss.getSheetByName("Labor Log");
  var a1Not = "I21:I";
  
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    if (sheet.getName() != "Labor Log") {
      let range = sheet.getRange(a1Not);
      let laborCells = range.createTextFinder("Labor").findAll();
      
      laborCells.forEach(function(cell) {
        let data = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), 8, 1, 8).getValues().flat();
        console.log(data);
        let newRow = [ "", data[0], data[6], data[2]];
        log.appendRow(newRow);        
      });
    }
  });  
}
```

**Rundown of this function:**

- Gets all the sheets from the bound Spreadsheet
- If the Sheet name ***is not*** `Labor Log`, then:

  - Searches down the range `I21:I` for the keyword "Labor"
  - Gets the range `Hא:Oא` where `א` is the row that contains the word "Labor" in column `I`
  - Appends the Date, Duration and Description from that row to the Sheet named `Labor Log`

You can either run this from the Script editor page by pressing the run button (▶), or by setting up a button from inside the Spreadsheet. **Make sure to save the script!**

#### Assigning to a Button:

You can create an in-sheet button which will run the script whenever you click it.

1. Go to the `Insert > Drawing` menu item from the Sheets interface and create a shape; any shape will do, this will act as your button.
2. Press `Save and Close` to add this to your sheet.
3. Move the newly-added drawing to where you would like. In the top-right of the drawing, you will see the vertical ellipsis menu (`⋮`). Click this, and then click `Assign script`.
4. In the new window, type `appendToLog` and press `OK`.

Now, each time you click the button, the script will run.

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)